# Open video to time offset in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to open a mp4 web asset in an ios app to a specific set of time offsets, like chapters for example, 2:31 in to a 10 minute video

any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure about the video asset, but for an audio piece, when you create an audioPlayer, just set [audioPlayer setCurrentTime:4.31];

Comment: Are you intending to add this content as meta data to the video asset or are you looking to create these offsets in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an AVAssetReader and set a time range before starting to read frames:

```
CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, kCMTimePositiveInfinity);
assetReader.timeRange = timeRange;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have an [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which you're already using to play the movie, I suggest looking at the `initialPlaybackTime` and `endPlaybackTime` properties on the controller to set the start and end point for movie playback.